# using mail() with Mac OS X localhost server

Tags: php, terminal, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to get PHP's mail() function working with my localhost in Mac OS X Mavericks. It works fine if I host using my actual website server, but that's not very useful for the development stage.

So far I tried:

- Adding `MAILSERVER=-YES-` to hostconfig file
- Starting postfix through terminal
- A bunch of other random things (too many to list here!)

Anyone know a proper solution to get mail to send when testing website forms from a local computer?

Comment: Does the `mail()` function return `true` or `false`? If it returns `true`, it is a server configuration problem and you are probably better off using a real mail server.

Comment: @jeroen It's not a problem with the code or the PHP, it's the way my Mac mail server has been set up. I don't want to have to upload my website to a eal server every time I want to test a web form. I should be able to do that with the build-in Mac server.

Comment: You don't need to upload the whole web-site, you just need to connect to a real mail server. You could of course configure your mac as a mail server, but that would probably only work when you deliver your mail locally as mail sent from a "normal" computer to a mail server on the internet will probably never be accepted; it will be labeled as spam if delivered at all.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. I did try following a tutorial that connected to a gmail server to avoid the spam issue. Still no luck. I was really just looking for a step-by-step process of any files I need to change to get it working.

Comment: You can use http://swiftmailer.org/ library to connect to email servers and use them externally.